# Ad hoc implementation of cruise control

Tags: c, simulation

I've written a small C program that has ad hoc implementation of cruise control for my Altera DE2 FPGA. It works alright but there are too many global variables. Preferably there should be no global variables. How can I reduce the amount of global variables?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "system.h"
#include "includes.h"
#include "altera_avalon_pio_regs.h"
#include "sys/alt_irq.h"
#include "sys/alt_alarm.h"
#include "altera_avalon_pio_regs.h"
#include "alt_types.h"
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/alt_timestamp.h>
#include <sys/alt_cache.h>


#define N 8192

#define M 32

#define DEBUG 1

#define HW_TIMER_PERIOD 100 /* 100ms */

/* Button Patterns */

#define GAS_PEDAL_FLAG      0x08
#define BRAKE_PEDAL_FLAG    0x04
#define CRUISE_CONTROL_FLAG 0x02
/* Switch Patterns */

#define TOP_GEAR_FLAG       0x00000002
#define ENGINE_FLAG         0x00000001

/* LED Patterns */

#define LED_RED_0 0x00000001 // Engine
#define LED_RED_1 0x00000002 // Top Gear

#define LED_GREEN_0 0x0001 // Cruise Control activated
#define LED_GREEN_2 0x0002 // Cruise Control Button
#define LED_GREEN_3 0x0004 // Cruise Control Button
#define LED_GREEN_4 0x0010 // Brake Pedal
#define LED_GREEN_6 0x0040 // Gas Pedal

#define TASK_STACKSIZE 2048

OS_STK StartTask_Stack[TASK_STACKSIZE];
OS_STK ControlTask_Stack[TASK_STACKSIZE];
OS_STK VehicleTask_Stack[TASK_STACKSIZE];
OS_STK VehicleTask_Stack[TASK_STACKSIZE];
OS_STK WatchdogTask_Stack[TASK_STACKSIZE];
OS_STK DetectionTask_Stack[TASK_STACKSIZE];
// Task Priorities

#define STARTTASK_PRIO 5
#define VEHICLETASK_PRIO 10
#define CONTROLTASK_PRIO 12
#define DETECTIONTASK_PRIO 13
#define WATCHDOGTASK_PRIO 14


// Task Periods

#define CONTROL_PERIOD  300
#define VEHICLE_PERIOD  300

/*
 * Definition of Kernel Objects
 */

// Mailboxes
OS_EVENT *Mbox_Throttle;
OS_EVENT *Mbox_Velocity;
OS_EVENT *Mbox_Writeok;

// Semaphores
OS_EVENT *aSemaphore;
OS_EVENT *aSemaphore2;

// SW-Timer
OS_TMR *SWTimer;
alt_u32 ticks;
alt_u32 time_1;
alt_u32 time_2;
alt_u32 timer_overhead;
/*
 * Types
 */
enum active {on, off};

enum active gas_pedal = off;
enum active brake_pedal = off;
enum active top_gear = off;
enum active engine = off;
enum active cruise_control = off;

/*
 * Global variables
 */
int delay; // Delay of HW-timer
INT16U led_green = 0; // Green LEDs
INT32U led_red = 0;   // Red LEDs
/*alt_u32 ticks;
alt_u32 time_1;
alt_u32 time_2;
alt_u32 timer_overhead;*/
void TimerCallback(params)
{
    // Post to the semaphore to signal that it's time to run the task.
    OSSemPost(aSemaphore); // Releasing the key


}

int buttons_pressed(void)
{
    return ~IORD_ALTERA_AVALON_PIO_DATA(DE2_PIO_KEYS4_BASE);
}

int switches_pressed(void)
{
    return IORD_ALTERA_AVALON_PIO_DATA(DE2_PIO_TOGGLES18_BASE);
}

/*
 * ISR for HW Timer
 */
alt_u32 alarm_handler(void* context)
{
    OSTmrSignal(); /* Signals a 'tick' to the SW timers */

    return delay;
}

void release()
{
    OSSemPost(aSemaphore);
    OSSemPost(aSemaphore2);

}
/*void shownumberonleds(int x)
{
IOWR_ALTERA_AVALON_PIO_DATA( LED_PIO_BASE , x ) ;
}*/

static int b2sLUT[] = {0x40, //0
                       0x79, //1
                       0x24, //2
                       0x30, //3
                       0x19, //4
                       0x12, //5
                       0x02, //6
                       0x78, //7
                       0x00, //8
                       0x18, //9
                       0x3F, //-
                      };

/*
 * convert int to seven segment display format
 */
int int2seven(int inval) {
    return b2sLUT[inval];
}

/*
 * output current velocity on the seven segement display
 */
void show_velocity_on_sevenseg(INT8S velocity) {
    int tmp = velocity;
    int out;
    INT8U out_high = 0;
    INT8U out_low = 0;
    INT8U out_sign = 0;

    if (velocity < 0) {
        out_sign = int2seven(10);
        tmp *= -1;
    } else {
        out_sign = int2seven(0);
    }

    out_high = int2seven(tmp / 10);
    out_low = int2seven(tmp - (tmp/10) * 10);

    out = int2seven(0) << 21 |
          out_sign << 14 |
          out_high << 7  |
          out_low;
    IOWR_ALTERA_AVALON_PIO_DATA(DE2_PIO_HEX_LOW28_BASE,out);
}


/*
 * output current position on the seven segement display
 */
void show_position_on_sevenseg(INT8S position) {


}

void show_target_velocity(INT8S velocity) {
    int tmp = velocity;
    int out;
    INT8U out_high = 0;
    INT8U out_low = 0;
    INT8U out_sign = 0;

    if (velocity < 0) {
        out_sign = int2seven(10);
        tmp *= -1;
    } else {
        out_sign = int2seven(0);
    }

    out_high = int2seven(tmp / 10);
    out_low = int2seven(tmp - (tmp/10) * 10);

    out = int2seven(0) << 21 |
          out_sign << 14 |
          out_high << 7  |
          out_low;
    if (cruise_control == 0) {
        IOWR_ALTERA_AVALON_PIO_DATA(DE2_PIO_HEX_HIGH28_BASE,out);
        IOWR_ALTERA_AVALON_PIO_DATA(DE2_PIO_GREENLED9_BASE, LED_GREEN_0);
    } else {

        IOWR_ALTERA_AVALON_PIO_DATA(DE2_PIO_HEX_HIGH28_BASE,0x00);
    }
}

/*
 * indicates the position of the vehicle on the track with the four leftmost red LEDs
 * LEDR17: [0m, 400m)
 * LEDR16: [400m, 800m)
 * LEDR15: [800m, 1200m)
 * LEDR14: [1200m, 1600m)
 * LEDR13: [1600m, 2000m)
 * LEDR12: [2000m, 2400m]
 */
void show_position(INT16U position)
{
    int out = 0;
    if ( engine == 1 && top_gear == 1) {
        if (position <= 400) {
            out = 0x20000;
            IOWR_ALTERA_AVALON_PIO_DATA(DE2_PIO_REDLED18_BASE,out);
        }
        else if (position >= 400 && position <= 800) {
            out = 0x30000;
            IOWR_ALTERA_AVALON_PIO_DATA(DE2_PIO_REDLED18_BASE,out);
        } else if (position >= 800 && position <= 1200) {
            out = 0x38000;
            IOWR_ALTERA_AVALON_PIO_DATA(DE2_PIO_REDLED18_BASE,out);
        } else if (position >=1200 && position <= 1600) {
            out = 0x3C000;
            IOWR_ALTERA_AVALON_PIO_DATA(DE2_PIO_REDLED18_BASE,out);
        } else if (position >= 1600 && position <= 2000) {
            out = 0x3E000;
            IOWR_ALTERA_AVALON_PIO_DATA(DE2_PIO_REDLED18_BASE,out);
        }
        else if (position >= 2000 && position <= 2400) {
            out = 0x3F000;
            IOWR_ALTERA_AVALON_PIO_DATA(DE2_PIO_REDLED18_BASE,out);
        } else if (position >= 2400) {
            out = 0x3F000;
            IOWR_ALTERA_AVALON_PIO_DATA(DE2_PIO_REDLED18_BASE,out);
        }
    } else if ( engine == 0 && top_gear == 1) {
        if (position <= 400) {
            out = 0x20001;
            IOWR_ALTERA_AVALON_PIO_DATA(DE2_PIO_REDLED18_BASE,out);
        }
        else if (position >= 400 && position <= 800) {
            out = 0x30001;
            IOWR_ALTERA_AVALON_PIO_DATA(DE2_PIO_REDLED18_BASE,out);
        } else if (position >= 800 && position <= 1200) {
            out = 0x38001;
            IOWR_ALTERA_AVALON_PIO_DATA(DE2_PIO_REDLED18_BASE,out);
        } else if (position >=1200 && position <= 1600) {
            out = 0x3C001;
            IOWR_ALTERA_AVALON_PIO_DATA(DE2_PIO_REDLED18_BASE,out);
        } else if (position >= 1600 && position <= 2000) {
            out = 0x3E001;
            IOWR_ALTERA_AVALON_PIO_DATA(DE2_PIO_REDLED18_BASE,out);
        }
        else if (position >= 2000 && position <= 2400) {
            out = 0x3F001;
            IOWR_ALTERA_AVALON_PIO_DATA(DE2_PIO_REDLED18_BASE,out);
        }  else if (position >= 2400) {
            out = 0x3F001;
            IOWR_ALTERA_AVALON_PIO_DATA(DE2_PIO_REDLED18_BASE,out);
        }
    }
    else if ( engine == 0 && top_gear == 0) {

        if (position <= 400) {
            int out = 0x20003;
            IOWR_ALTERA_AVALON_PIO_DATA(DE2_PIO_REDLED18_BASE,out);
        }
        else if (position >= 400 && position <= 800) {
            int out = 0x30003;
            IOWR_ALTERA_AVALON_PIO_DATA(DE2_PIO_REDLED18_BASE,out);
        }
        else if (position >= 800 && position <= 1200) {
            int out = 0x38003;
            IOWR_ALTERA_AVALON_PIO_DATA(DE2_PIO_REDLED18_BASE,out);
        }
        else if (position >=1200 && position <= 1600) {
            int out = 0x3C003;
            IOWR_ALTERA_AVALON_PIO_DATA(DE2_PIO_REDLED18_BASE,out);
        }
        else if (position >= 1600 && position <= 2000) {
            int out = 0x3E003;
            IOWR_ALTERA_AVALON_PIO_DATA(DE2_PIO_REDLED18_BASE,out);
        }
        else if (position >= 2000 && position <= 2400) {
            int out = 0x3F003;
            IOWR_ALTERA_AVALON_PIO_DATA(DE2_PIO_REDLED18_BASE,out);
        }
        else if (position >= 2400) {
            int out = 0x3F003;
            IOWR_ALTERA_AVALON_PIO_DATA(DE2_PIO_REDLED18_BASE,out);
        }

    }
}

/*
 * The function 'adjust_position()' adjusts the position depending on the
 * acceleration and velocity.
 */
INT16U adjust_position(INT16U position, INT16S velocity,
                       INT8S acceleration, INT16U time_interval)
{
    INT16S new_position = position + velocity * time_interval / 1000
                          + acceleration / 2  * (time_interval / 1000) * (time_interval / 1000);

    if (new_position > 24000) {
        new_position -= 24000;
    } else if (new_position < 0) {
        new_position += 24000;
    }

    //show_position(new_position);
    return new_position;
}

/*
 * The function 'adjust_velocity()' adjusts the velocity depending on the
 * acceleration.
 */
INT16S adjust_velocity(INT16S velocity, INT8S acceleration,
                       enum active brake_pedal, INT16U time_interval)
{
    INT16S new_velocity;
    INT8U brake_retardation = 200;

    if (brake_pedal == off)
        new_velocity = velocity  + (float) (acceleration * time_interval) / 1000.0;
    else {
        if (brake_retardation * time_interval / 1000 > velocity)
            new_velocity = 0;
        else
            new_velocity = velocity - brake_retardation * time_interval / 1000;
    }

    return new_velocity;
}

int cruise_velocity =0;
int cruise_control_increase_velocity = 0;
int cruise_control_decrease_velocity = 0;
void Button1IO(INT16S* current_velocity)
{
    printf("Button1IO %d\n", buttons_pressed() );
    if (buttons_pressed()==-14 && *current_velocity >= 20 && top_gear == on && gas_pedal == off && brake_pedal==off) {
        cruise_control = on;
        cruise_velocity = *current_velocity;
        show_target_velocity(cruise_velocity/10);
        IOWR_ALTERA_AVALON_PIO_DATA(DE2_PIO_GREENLED9_BASE, LED_GREEN_0);
        IOWR_ALTERA_AVALON_PIO_DATA(DE2_PIO_GREENLED9_BASE, LED_GREEN_2);
    }
    else if (buttons_pressed() == -16) {
        if (cruise_control == 0 && cruise_velocity > *current_velocity && cruise_velocity >0) {
            cruise_control_increase_velocity = 1;
            IOWR_ALTERA_AVALON_PIO_DATA(DE2_PIO_GREENLED9_BASE, LED_GREEN_0);
        } else if (cruise_control == 0 && cruise_velocity < *current_velocity && cruise_velocity >0) {
            cruise_control_decrease_velocity = 1;
            IOWR_ALTERA_AVALON_PIO_DATA(DE2_PIO_GREENLED9_BASE, LED_GREEN_0);
        } else {

            IOWR_ALTERA_AVALON_PIO_DATA(DE2_PIO_GREENLED9_BASE, 0x0000);
        }
    }
    printf("buttons_pressed: %d\n",buttons_pressed() );
}

void Button2IO(INT16S current_velocity)
{
    if (buttons_pressed() == -12) {
        brake_pedal = on;
        cruise_control = off;
        IOWR_ALTERA_AVALON_PIO_DATA(DE2_PIO_GREENLED9_BASE,0x00000);//clear
        IOWR_ALTERA_AVALON_PIO_DATA(DE2_PIO_GREENLED9_BASE,LED_GREEN_4);
        cruise_velocity = 0;
        IOWR_ALTERA_AVALON_PIO_DATA(DE2_PIO_HEX_HIGH28_BASE,0x00);//clear target velocity
    }
    else {
        brake_pedal = off;
        if (! cruise_velocity > 0  ) {
            IOWR_ALTERA_AVALON_PIO_DATA(DE2_PIO_GREENLED9_BASE,0x00000);
        } else {
            if (cruise_control == 0) {
                IOWR_ALTERA_AVALON_PIO_DATA(DE2_PIO_GREENLED9_BASE, LED_GREEN_0);
            }
        }
    }
}
void ButtonIO(INT16S* current_velocity, INT8U throttle)
{
    int btn_reg = IORD_ALTERA_AVALON_PIO_DATA(DE2_PIO_KEYS4_BASE);
    if (btn_reg == 7) { //buttons_pressed() == -8){
        gas_pedal = on;
        cruise_control = off;
        IOWR_ALTERA_AVALON_PIO_DATA(DE2_PIO_GREENLED9_BASE,LED_GREEN_6);
    } else if (buttons_pressed() == -16) {
        gas_pedal = off;
        if (! cruise_velocity > 0  ) {
            IOWR_ALTERA_AVALON_PIO_DATA(DE2_PIO_GREENLED9_BASE,0x00000);
        } else {
            IOWR_ALTERA_AVALON_PIO_DATA(DE2_PIO_GREENLED9_BASE, LED_GREEN_0);
        }
    }
    printf("ButtonIO buttons_pressed: %d\n",  buttons_pressed());
}
float microseconds(int ticks)
{
    return (float) 1000000 * (float) ticks / (float) alt_timestamp_freq();
}
void initArray(int x[], int n)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        x[i] = i;
}
void start_measurement()
{
    /* Flush caches */
    alt_dcache_flush_all();
    alt_icache_flush_all();
    /* Measure */
    alt_timestamp_start();
    time_1 = alt_timestamp();
}
void stop_measurement()
{
    time_2 = alt_timestamp();
    ticks = time_2 - time_1;
}
void SwitchIO(INT16S* current_velocity, int position)
{
    int w[700];
    int tmp = 600;
    int x[13];
    int a, b;
    int size = M;
    int i, j;
    timer_overhead = 0;

    if (switches_pressed()==1) {
        engine = on;
        top_gear=off;
        show_position(position);
        printf("The engine is turned on\n");
    } else  if (switches_pressed()==3) {
        engine = on;
        top_gear=on;
        show_position(position);
    }
    else if (switches_pressed()==0) {
        printf("switches_pressed()==0\n");
        top_gear = off;
        engine = off;
        show_position(position);
    }
    else if (switches_pressed()==2) {

    }
    else if ((switches_pressed()-19)/16 >= 0) {
        int number = (switches_pressed()-19)/16+1;
        if (number > 50) {
            number = 50;
        }
        printf("extra load %d\n", number);
        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            start_measurement();
            stop_measurement();
            timer_overhead = timer_overhead + time_2 - time_1;
        }
        initArray(w, 600);
        initArray(x, 13);
        start_measurement();

        j=tmp+number*4;
        for (i = 0; i < j; i++)
            w[i]++;
        stop_measurement();
        printf("%5.2f us", (float) microseconds(ticks - timer_overhead));
        printf("(%d ticks)\n", (int) (ticks - timer_overhead));

    }
    printf("switches_pressed: %d\n", switches_pressed());
    printf("switches_pressed: %d\n", (switches_pressed()-19)/16);

}

void pollkey()
{
    int btn_reg;
    static int last_value = -1;
    btn_reg = IORD_ALTERA_AVALON_PIO_DATA(DE2_PIO_KEYS4_BASE);
    btn_reg = (~btn_reg) & 0xf;
    if (last_value != btn_reg)
    {
        last_value = btn_reg;
        switch (btn_reg)
        {
        case 1:
            //run = 1;
            break;
        case 2:
            //run = 0;
            break;
        case 4:
            //tick (&timeloc);
            break;
        case 8:
            //timeloc = 0;
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
}


int globalPosition = 0;

void setGlobalPosition(int position) {

    globalPosition = position;
}

int getGlobalPosition() {
    return globalPosition;
}
/*
 * The task 'VehicleTask' updates the current velocity of the vehicle
 */
void VehicleTask(void* pdata)
{
    INT8U err;
    void* msg;
    INT8U* throttle;
    INT8S acceleration;  /* Value between 40 and -20 (4.0 m/s^2 and -2.0 m/s^2) */
    INT8S retardation;   /* Value between 20 and -10 (2.0 m/s^2 and -1.0 m/s^2) */
    INT16U position = 0; /* Value between 0 and 20000 (0.0 m and 2000.0 m)  */
    INT16S velocity = 0; /* Value between -200 and 700 (-20.0 m/s amd 70.0 m/s) */
    INT16S wind_factor;   /* Value between -10 and 20 (2.0 m/s^2 and -1.0 m/s^2) */

    printf("Vehicle task created!\n");
    while (1)
    {
        OSSemPend(aSemaphore, 0, &err); // Trying to access the key
        err = OSMboxPost(Mbox_Velocity, (void *) &velocity);
        /* Non-blocking read of mailbox:
         - message in mailbox: update throttle
         - no message:         use old throttle
        */
        msg = OSMboxPend(Mbox_Throttle, 1, &err);
        if (err == OS_NO_ERR)
            throttle = (INT8U*) msg;

        /* Retardation : Factor of Terrain and Wind Resistance */
        if (velocity > 0)
            wind_factor = velocity * velocity / 10000 + 1;
        else
            wind_factor = (-1) * velocity * velocity / 10000 + 1;

        if (position < 4000)
            retardation = wind_factor; // even ground
        else if (position < 8000)
            retardation = wind_factor + 15; // traveling uphill
        else if (position < 12000)
            retardation = wind_factor + 25; // traveling steep uphill
        else if (position < 16000)
            retardation = wind_factor; // even ground
        else if (position < 20000)
            retardation = wind_factor - 10; //traveling downhill
        else
            retardation = wind_factor - 5 ; // traveling steep downhill

        acceleration = *throttle / 2 - retardation;
        position = adjust_position(position, velocity, acceleration, 300);
        setGlobalPosition(position);
        velocity = adjust_velocity(velocity, acceleration, brake_pedal, 300);
        //printf("Position: %dm\n", position / 10);
        show_position(position);
        printf("Velocity: %4.1fm/s\n", velocity /10.0);
        printf("Throttle: %dV\n", *throttle / 10);
        show_velocity_on_sevenseg((INT8S) (velocity / 10));
        // break inside vehicle task
        Button2IO( (velocity/10) );
    }
}

/*
 * The task 'ControlTask' is the main task of the application. It reacts
 * on sensors and generates responses.
 */

void ControlTask(void* pdata)
{
    INT8U err;
    INT8U throttle = 40; /* Value between 0 and 80, which is interpreted as between 0.0V and 8.0V */
    void* msg;
    INT16S* current_velocity;
    int btn_reg;
    INT16S* current_output;
    printf("Control Task created!\n");

    while (1)
    {

        OSSemPend(aSemaphore, 1, &err); // Trying to access the key
        msg = OSMboxPend(Mbox_Velocity, 0, &err);
        current_velocity = (INT16S*) msg;
        //printf("Control Task!\n");
        ButtonIO(current_velocity, throttle);
        btn_reg = IORD_ALTERA_AVALON_PIO_DATA(DE2_PIO_KEYS4_BASE);
        //printf("btn_reg %d\n", btn_reg);
        int increment = 30;
        if (btn_reg == 7) {
            ++throttle;
        } else if (cruise_control_increase_velocity == 1) {
            //printf("increase velocity \n");
            if (*current_velocity <= cruise_velocity) {
                throttle = throttle + increment - 16;
            }


            cruise_control_increase_velocity = 0;
        }
        else if (btn_reg == 11) {
            if (throttle > 0) {
                --throttle;
            }

        } else if (cruise_control_decrease_velocity == 1 && throttle >= increment && * current_velocity >= cruise_velocity) {
            //printf("decrease_velocity \n");

                throttle = throttle -increment;

            cruise_control_decrease_velocity = 0;
        }
        if (btn_reg== 13) {
            //printf("do cruise control\n" );
            cruise_velocity = *current_velocity;
        }
        Button1IO(current_velocity);
        SwitchIO(current_velocity, getGlobalPosition());
        err = OSMboxPost(Mbox_Throttle, (void *) &throttle);
    }
}
void WatchDogTask(void* pdata)
{
    INT8U err;
    void* msg;
    INT8U* throttle;
    printf("Watchdog task created!\n");
    INT16S* current_output;
    OS_SEM_DATA sem_data;
    INT8U err2;
    int i;
    while (1)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            start_measurement();
            stop_measurement();
            timer_overhead = timer_overhead + time_2 - time_1;
        }

        start_measurement();
        OSSemPend(aSemaphore2, 1, &err); // Trying to access the key
        msg = OSMboxPend(Mbox_Writeok, 0, &err);
        current_output = (INT16S*) msg;
        printf("Watchdog:%d\n", * current_output);
        if ( * current_output != 17 ) {
            printf("System overload:%d\n", * current_output);
        }

        stop_measurement();
        float measure = (float) microseconds(ticks - timer_overhead);
        if (measure > 7600 && measure < 10000) {
            printf("Overload warning");
        }
        printf("Watchdog %5.2f us", (float) microseconds(ticks - timer_overhead));
        printf("(%d ticks)\n", (int) (ticks - timer_overhead));


        current_output = 0;
    }
}
void DetectionTask(void* pdata)
{
    INT8U err;
    printf("DetectionTask created!\n");
    int next = 17;
    while (1)
    {
        OSSemPend(aSemaphore2, 0, &err); // Trying to access the key
        err = OSMboxPost(Mbox_Writeok, (void *) &next);
        /* Check “err” */

    }
}
/*
 * The task 'StartTask' creates all other tasks kernel objects and
 * deletes itself afterwards.
 */

void StartTask(void* pdata)
{
    INT8U err;
    void* context;
    IOWR_ALTERA_AVALON_PIO_DATA(DE2_PIO_REDLED18_BASE,0X00000);
    IOWR_ALTERA_AVALON_PIO_DATA(DE2_PIO_HEX_HIGH28_BASE,0X00000);
    static alt_alarm alarm;     /* Is needed for timer ISR function */

    /* Base resolution for SW timer : HW_TIMER_PERIOD ms */
    delay = alt_ticks_per_second() * HW_TIMER_PERIOD / 1000;
    printf("delay in ticks %d\n", delay);
    //printf("Starting time measurement\n");
    //startTimeMeasurement();
    /*
     * Create Hardware Timer with a period of 'delay'
     */
    if (alt_alarm_start (&alarm,
                         delay,
                         alarm_handler,
                         context) < 0)
    {
        printf("No system clock available!n");
    }

    /*
     * Create and start Software Timer
     */

    SWTimer = OSTmrCreate(0,
                          CONTROL_PERIOD/(4*OS_TMR_CFG_TICKS_PER_SEC),
                          OS_TMR_OPT_PERIODIC,
                          release,
                          NULL,
                          NULL,
                          &err);
    if (err == OS_ERR_NONE) {
        /* Timer was created but NOT started */
        printf("SWTimer was created but NOT started \n");
    }

    BOOLEAN status = OSTmrStart(SWTimer,
                                &err);
    if (status > 0 && err == OS_ERR_NONE) {
        /* Timer was started */
        printf("SWTimer was started!\n");
    }
    /*
     * Creation of Kernel Objects
     */

    // Mailboxes
    Mbox_Throttle = OSMboxCreate((void*) 0); /* Empty Mailbox - Throttle */
    Mbox_Velocity = OSMboxCreate((void*) 0); /* Empty Mailbox - Velocity */
    Mbox_Writeok = OSMboxCreate((void*) 0); /* Empty Mailbox - Write ok */

    /*
     * Create statistics task
     */

    OSStatInit();

    /*
     * Creating Tasks in the system
     */

    err = OSTaskCreateExt(
              ControlTask, // Pointer to task code
              NULL,        // Pointer to argument that is
              // passed to task
              &ControlTask_Stack[TASK_STACKSIZE-1], // Pointer to top
              // of task stack
              CONTROLTASK_PRIO,
              CONTROLTASK_PRIO,
              (void *)&ControlTask_Stack[0],
              TASK_STACKSIZE,
              (void *) 0,
              OS_TASK_OPT_STK_CHK);

    err = OSTaskCreateExt(
              VehicleTask, // Pointer to task code
              NULL,        // Pointer to argument that is
              // passed to task
              &VehicleTask_Stack[TASK_STACKSIZE-1], // Pointer to top
              // of task stack
              VEHICLETASK_PRIO,
              VEHICLETASK_PRIO,
              (void *)&VehicleTask_Stack[0],
              TASK_STACKSIZE,
              (void *) 0,
              OS_TASK_OPT_STK_CHK);

    err = OSTaskCreateExt(
              WatchDogTask, // Pointer to task code
              NULL,        // Pointer to argument that is
              // passed to task
              &WatchdogTask_Stack[TASK_STACKSIZE-1], // Pointer to top
              // of task stack
              WATCHDOGTASK_PRIO,
              WATCHDOGTASK_PRIO,
              (void *)&WatchdogTask_Stack[0],
              TASK_STACKSIZE,
              (void *) 0,
              OS_TASK_OPT_STK_CHK);

    err = OSTaskCreateExt(
              DetectionTask, // Pointer to task code
              NULL,        // Pointer to argument that is
              // passed to task
              &DetectionTask_Stack[TASK_STACKSIZE-1], // Pointer to top
              // of task stack
              DETECTIONTASK_PRIO,
              DETECTIONTASK_PRIO,
              (void *)&DetectionTask_Stack[0],
              TASK_STACKSIZE,
              (void *) 0,
              OS_TASK_OPT_STK_CHK);



    printf("All Tasks and Kernel Objects generated!\n");
    /* Task deletes itself */

    OSTaskDel(OS_PRIO_SELF);
}

int main(void) {

    printf("Cruise Control 20141010\n");
    aSemaphore = OSSemCreate(1); // binary semaphore (1 key)
    aSemaphore2 = OSSemCreate(1); // binary semaphore (1 key)

    OSTaskCreateExt(
        StartTask, // Pointer to task code
        NULL,      // Pointer to argument that is
        // passed to task
        (void *)&StartTask_Stack[TASK_STACKSIZE-1], // Pointer to top
        // of task stack
        STARTTASK_PRIO,
        STARTTASK_PRIO,
        (void *)&StartTask_Stack[0],
        TASK_STACKSIZE,
        (void *) 0,
        OS_TASK_OPT_STK_CHK | OS_TASK_OPT_STK_CLR);

    OSStart();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I hope this was hard to write.  It's certainly hard to read.  Code Review looks like the *perfect* spot for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wow, I don't know where to start. I think I'll just work on one function.

> ```
> void SwitchIO(INT16S* current_velocity, int position)
> {
>     int w[700];
>     int tmp = 600;
>     int x[13];
>     int a, b;
>     int size = M;
>     int i, j;
>     timer_overhead = 0;
>
>     if (switches_pressed()==1) {
>         engine = on;
>         top_gear=off;
>         show_position(position);
>         printf("The engine is turned on\n");
>     } else  if (switches_pressed()==3) {
>         engine = on;
>         top_gear=on;
>         show_position(position);
>     }
>     else if (switches_pressed()==0) {
>         printf("switches_pressed()==0\n");
>         top_gear = off;
>         engine = off;
>         show_position(position);
>     }
>     else if (switches_pressed()==2) {
>
>     }
>     else if ((switches_pressed()-19)/16 >= 0) {
>         int number = (switches_pressed()-19)/16+1;
>         if (number > 50) {
>             number = 50;
>         }
>         printf("extra load %d\n", number);
>         for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
>             start_measurement();
>             stop_measurement();
>             timer_overhead = timer_overhead + time_2 - time_1;
>         }
>         initArray(w, 600);
>         initArray(x, 13);
>         start_measurement();
>
>         j=tmp+number*4;
>         for (i = 0; i < j; i++)
>             w[i]++;
>         stop_measurement();
>         printf("%5.2f us", (float) microseconds(ticks - timer_overhead));
>         printf("(%d ticks)\n", (int) (ticks - timer_overhead));
>
>     }
>     printf("switches_pressed: %d\n", switches_pressed());
>     printf("switches_pressed: %d\n", (switches_pressed()-19)/16);
>
> }
> ```

I'm not sure what the intent is here. Part of the problem is the completely obscure variable names and values. What is `w` and why does it need to be of size 700? And so forth.

Do you really mean to poll the status of `switches_pressed()` multiple times, and then only take one action? That doesn't seem logical to me. If I were writing something similar, I'd save the value of `switches_pressed()` into a temporary variable, and then use chained `if`s or a `switch` in order to take the appropriate action.

CONTINUING...

> ```
> #include "system.h"
> #include "includes.h"
> #include "altera_avalon_pio_regs.h"
> #include "sys/alt_irq.h"
> #include "sys/alt_alarm.h"
> #include "altera_avalon_pio_regs.h"
> #include "alt_types.h"
> ```

Can you post these files on pastebin, github, or some other textfile hosting site and include a link?

Why in the world do you `#include "altera_avalon_pio_regs.h"` twice?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It is a function that should add load to the system to cause a system overload when switches are on. I wasn't sure about how to write but it does generate a system overload.

Comment: I'm interested in anything that can change my program's behavovior so it's very good if you find even small bugs. And I'm sure there are large bugs. The code is on github https://github.com/montao/nios2rtos